# what are the advantages of MVC3 over MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am currently learning MVC2. actually working on my first MVC2 project.As the MVC3 beta is launched and available to download. please suggest me should i use MVC3(Beta) or continue with MVC2 and second thing is, if i move to MVC3 then what major advantages i will get from it. 
My project is an ERP application.
Please suggest me what should i do.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read the release notes for MVC3, and see what parts could benefit you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at this blog post from Scott Gu :

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx

To name some advantages, you can use the Razor View Engine, which depending on your requirements, it will make your view code nicer. I believe that's the case for an ERP System.

This is not 100% mvc3 related, but with the RC you get NuGet installed with it, if you're planning on using external libraries to help you out, that's a great way to manage them.

Partial Page output caching is a great feature for systems that share bits and pieces across different ui's.

Unobtrusive JavaScript and Validation is also another great new feature that will help you keep your code's maintainability among other benefits.

MVC3 also has some benefits from the dynamic aspects of .NET 4, and that also helps you keep your view code cleaner.

And my end point would be, MVC3 is already on RC stage....it already has Go Live license and support...if you're learning, I would suggest learning the latest, you will get all the knowledge you need to use mvc 1 and 2, and also the new things about mvc 3.

Comment: Thanks for providing such a valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

One factor is the release date of MVC 3 compared to the release date of your application, i.e. you should not ship an application based on a beta version of MVC.

If you switch to MVC 3 beta, you should be aware that there may be changes in the final release, so you may have to make changes for each version until the relase, and your application is only guaranteed to work with one specific pre-release version, until the final release of MVC 3.

Comment: The MVC 3 RC was released last week.

Comment: @RyanW: That is still a pre-release version. Unless you have a dedicated server, you will have a hard time finding hosting for MVC 3 until the release.